# Is there any equivalent to reduceByKeyAndWindow in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Would like to take advantage of Spark's Structured Streaming capabilities but I need to do a reduce by key within a window. Basic Spark Streaming supports a method called `reduceByKeyAndWindow`. I've done a lot of searching of the Spark Structured Streaming documentation but have not hit on anything that is equivalent to Spark Streaming's `reduceByKeyAndWindow`.

Is there any combination of the Structured Streaming operations that will allow me to do a reduce by key within a window?

Comment: Maybe this could be of help to you: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time

Answer (score 3):

In Structured Streaming lingo, `ReduceByKeyAndWindow` would be a window aggregation with a composite key.
Something like:

```scala
stream.groupBy($"key", window($"timestamp", "5 minutes"))
       .agg(sum($"value") as "total")
```

The aggregate could be any supported SQL function.